# How do I use static keyword inside class in C++ to emulate the behavior of @classmethod in Python?

Tags: python, c++, oop

I read somewhere that `@classmethod` in Python is similar to static member function in C++. But what is the equivalent `cls` parameter in C++ and how do I pass it?

Below is a Python code that uses inheritance and `@classmethod`,

```
class Parent():
    def __init__(self, name):
        self._name = name
    @classmethod
    def produce(cls, name):
        return cls(name)
    def say_my_name(self):
        print("I am parent", self._name)

class Child(Parent):
    def say_my_name(self):
        print("I am child", self._name)

p1 = Parent("One")
p1.say_my_name()
p2 = Parent.produce("Two")
p2.say_my_name()

p1 = Child("One")
p1.say_my_name()
p2 = Child.produce("Two")
p2.say_my_name()
```

And now I am stuck in my incomplete C++ code as follows

```
class Parent
{
    protected:
        std::string name;
    public:
        Parent(const std::string& name): name{name} {};

        // Can I not use static in the next statement?
        // Parent is already hard-coded, what's the cls in C++?
        static Parent produce(const std::string& name) const
        {
            return Parent {name};
        }
        void say_my_name() const
        {
            std::cout << "I am parent " << name << "\n";
        }
};
```

How can I emulate my Python code using C++?

Comment: "But what is the equivalent `cls` parameter in C++" - there's no equivalent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to emulate the use case you demonstrate in the Pynthon code some repetition is required:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class Parent
{
protected:
    std::string name;
public:
    Parent() = default;
    Parent(const std::string& name) : name{name} {};
    using cls = Parent; // this isn't normally done, normally Parent is just repeated

    // Can I not use static in the next statement?
    // Parent is already hard-coded, what's the cls in C++?
    //static Parent produce(const std::string& name) const
    cls produce(const std::string& name) const // static would mean the function does not belong to any object, so it must be removed if we want to call it on a temporary const object
    {
        return cls{name};
    }

    void say_my_name() const
    {
        std::cout << "I am parent " << name << "\n";
    }
}; 

class Child : public Parent {
public:
    using cls = Child; // this isn't normally done, normally Child is just repeated

    Child() = default;
    Child(const std::string& name) : Parent{name} {};

    void say_my_name() const
    {
        std::cout << "I am child " << name << "\n";
    }

    cls produce(const std::string& name) const  // have to repeat produce() here so that it hides Parent::produce().
    {
        return cls{name};
    }
};

int main()
{
    auto p1 = Parent("One");
    p1.say_my_name();
    auto p2 = Parent().produce("Two");
    p2.say_my_name();

    auto c1 = Child("One");
    c1.say_my_name();
    auto c2 = Child().produce("Two");
    c2.say_my_name();
}
```

This produces:

```
I am parent One
I am parent Two
I am child One
I am child Two
```

Here is a slightly modified version that uses `static`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class Parent
{
protected:
    std::string name;
public:
    Parent(const std::string& name) : name{name} {};
    using cls = Parent; // this isn't normally done, normally Parent is just repeated

                        // Can I not use static in the next statement?
                        // Parent is already hard-coded, what's the cls in C++?
                        //static Parent produce(const std::string& name) const
    static cls produce(const std::string& name) // here const would not make sense, this function will not be called on a particular instance of Parent
    {
        return cls{name};
    }

    void say_my_name() const
    {
        std::cout << "I am parent " << name << "\n";
    }
};

class Child : public Parent {
public:
    using cls = Child; // this isn't normally done, normally Child is just repeated

    Child(const std::string& name) : Parent{name} {};

    void say_my_name() const
    {
        std::cout << "I am child " << name << "\n";
    }

    static cls produce(const std::string& name) // have to repeat produce() here so that it hides Parent::produce().
    {
        return cls{name};
    }
};

int main()
{
    auto p1 = Parent("One");
    p1.say_my_name();
    auto p2 = Parent::produce("Two"); // No instance of Parent is used to create p2
    p2.say_my_name();

    auto c1 = Child("One");
    c1.say_my_name();
    auto c2 = Child::produce("Two");
    c2.say_my_name();
}
```

---

If however, we were to start from a clean slate, and wanted the result above. We could write:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class Parent
{
protected:
    std::string name;
public:
    Parent(const std::string& name) : name{name} {};

    void say_my_name() const
    {
        std::cout << "I am parent " << name << "\n";
    }
}; 

class Child : public Parent {
public:
    Child(const std::string& name) : Parent{name} {};

    void say_my_name() const
    {
        std::cout << "I am child " << name << "\n";
    }
};

template <typename T>
T produce(const std::string& name)
{
    return{name};
}

int main()
{
    Parent p1{"One"};
    p1.say_my_name();
    auto p2 = produce<Parent>("Two");
    p2.say_my_name();

    Child c1{"One"};
    c1.say_my_name();
    auto c2 = produce<Child>("Two");
    c2.say_my_name();
}
```

Comment: Beautiful, just one question when you used template, you wrote `return{name};` rather than `return T{name};` (I've never seen this before), is it true that this magic syntax treats whatever inside `{}` as the arguments in the constructor of class `T`?

Comment: @Nicholas `return{name};` uses [list-initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization) to initialize the [returned](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/return) object.

Answer (score 3):

`return Parent {name};` is correct. However, a static member function cannot be `const`, since there is no object on which it is called.

There is no built-in way to specify "the type of the current class" in C++. You just have to write `Parent` again. Unfortunately, that means that if you change the name of the class, you also have to change all relevant occurrences in the class's implementation.

Comment: My current understanding of `const` function is that it makes `const` class object able to call it, and this is important because we normally pass class object as `const` reference. So are you suggesting there is no way we can call the `static produce()` via a const class object? Or is it just a C++ rule that whenever a static member function is used, NO `const`? My second question is if we have to write `Parent` again, then we probably can't inherit `produce()` function and have to redefine `produce()` in `Child` class again, is this also your point? How do you write that in C++? thanks.

Comment: @Nicholas When you call a static member function, there is no object instance.